# Try {} catch(error) {} error when printing (error) in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The `print(error)` component of my catches:
`catch(error)`
does not work in Flutter/Dart

This is very odd.. it was working before, now I'm receiving an error telling me that my print statement is taking in too many arguments.

Here's a typical example:

```
accessDB() async
   {

    try
    {
     io.Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     String databasePath = join(appDocDir.path, kDBName);
     this.db = await openDatabase(databasePath);
     initialized = true;
    }
    catch(error)
     {
       print(error);
       initialized = false;
     }
   }
```

The error message is:
`Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, 1 found.`

but a print statement takes in 1 argument anyway: `print(error)`.

Answer (score 0):

This was my 1st post, and I found the answer. It was very odd.

My try/catches all had print(error) or print(e) outputs in the catches. They stopped working.

The reason? In a function within a class, I had a print statement that was empty:

print();

I erased it, and now there's no more issue.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?  This seems highly dubious.  I think it's more likely that you possibly accidentally defined your own `print` function that takes 0 arguments.